# Beamer footnote in a slide note

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I have a beamer slide and a note.  Each text has a footnote.  In the slide, the footnote mark and the footnote text appear where they should. In the note, the footnote mark appears int he right place, but the footnote text is missing. How can I make it appear?

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{frame}
Stuff\footnote[frame]{footnoted}
\note{Chat about stuff.\footnote{footnoted too}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack the note pack like this to show footnotes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{}{
\begingroup
\vfill
\usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
\footnoterule%
\unvbox \beamer@footins%
\global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
\endgroup  
\vskip0.2cm
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{frame}
Stuff\footnote[frame]{footnoted}
\note{Chat about stuff.\footnote{footnoted too}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.

Comment: @Augustin You're welcome!